# Can Quantum Zeno effect stabilize unstable particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem

Quantum Zeno effect says that a continuous measurement makes the state to be "unmoved". Could we use (at least in principle) this effect to make stable unstable particles?